# Invariant subspace (Proof)

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How do I prove, that the eigenspaces of $T^n$ are invariant in regard to $T$, assuming T is an endomorphism in a real vector space V $(T: V\rightarrow V)$?

That's how I started:

Let $E_\lambda$ be eigenspace of $\lambda$ in terms of $T$. Now, if $v\in E_\lambda$:

$T(v)=\lambda v\iff T^2(v)=T(T(v))=T(\lambda v)=\lambda^2v$

If this is correct, how do I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with an eigenspace of $T^n$, say $E_\lambda$ is an eigenspace of $T^n$ corresponding to $\lambda$. If $v\in E_\lambda$, then $T^n v=\lambda v$. You need to show that $Tv\in E_\lambda$, which follows from $T^n(Tv)=TT^nv=T(\lambda v)=\lambda Tv$.